Harry Potter fanfiction in which Harry goes to Snape's house and winds up in a relationship with Voldemort and Snape
The fanfiction involves Harry going to Snape's house on Spinner's End with Hedwig and Fawkes. Voldemort winds up there as a snake. Harry is cleaning the house and stays in his room and Snape doesn't realize that Harry is cleaning. Dumbledore tries to kill Snape with a sword. Moody and Remus are on Harry's side and Harry winds up in a relationship with Voldemort and Snape.I've been looking for this story for ages and I haven't had any luck on my own.
